# Scalar "exchange" in determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Consider the following:

> Find
> $$
>     \begin{vmatrix}
>     x^2+1 & xy & xz \\
>     xy & y^2+1 & yz \\
>     xz & yz & z^2+1 \\
>     \end{vmatrix}
> $$
> Multiplying $R_1,R_2,R_3$ with $x,y,z$ and dividing $C_1,C_2,C_3$ by $x,y,z$ respectively, we get
> $$
>     \begin{vmatrix}
>     x^2+1 & x^2 & x^2 \\
>     y^2 & y^2+1 & z^2 \\
>     z^2 & z^2 & z^2+1 \\
>     \end{vmatrix}
> $$

I have seen this technique of distributing scalars and taking them out being used extensively to simplify determinants quickly.

Is this a known "trick" in linear algebra? What is the intuition behind this? Are there some specific patterns of determinants where this technique proves helpful?

Comment: The $n-$determinant can be interpreted as a $n-$linear function of $n$ columns or equivalently $n$ vectors. This trick exploits the fact that the determinant is linear in its columns and its rows.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, a determinant is $n$ linear when multiplying a column or a row by a scalar is equivalent to multiplying the entire determinant by it. I have no idea about multilinear determinants and how they work. @DanielApsley

Comment: Right and it is even stronger than that. It just means that the determinant is a linear function in each of its variables. If your row vectors are given by $v_i$, then denoting $D$ the determinant function(see the description of the determinant in property 8 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant)) we have that $D(cv_1 + v_1', v_2, \dots, v_n) = cD(v_1, \dots, v_n) + cD(v_1', \dots, v_n)$ for any variable.

Comment: @DanielApsley I completely understood it(thanks). So your argument is that this can be applied to any linear determinant? I do doubt that this helps simplify most of them.

Comment: @DanielApsley There should be no $c$ in front of the third determinant in your equation.

Comment: Yes @Christoph is right. It would have been a typo

Answer (score 1):

the original matrix is better. Subtract the identity matrix, the result is the rank one  symmetric $v v^T,$  where $v^T = (x,y,z).$  The vector $v$ is also an eigenvector as $v v^T v  = v (v^T v), $  so that the eigenvalue is $x^2 + y^2 + z^2.$  The other two eigenvalues are $0.$

Now add in the identity matrix, this adds $1$ to each eigenvalue, now the eigenvalues are $1,1,1+x^2 + y^2 + z^2,$  while the determinant is  $1+x^2+y^2+z^2$

Comment: Actually I gave that determinant just as an example. The aim is to  discover a pattern/intuition to that method.

Answer (score 0):

1. Multiplying the $k$th row by $c$ is accomplished by multiplying on the left by the matrix $M(k,c)$ given by
   $$ M(k,c)_{ij}=\begin{cases} c, & i=j=k,\\ 1, &i=j\neq k, \\ 0 &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
2. Multiplying the $k$th column by $c$ is done by multiplying by $M(k,c)$ on the right.
3. Determinants of products are products of determinants: $|AB|=|A| |B|$, more generally $|A_1\dots A_n| = |A_1|\dots |A_n|$.
4. Let $$ A=\begin{bmatrix}
       x^2+1 & xy & xz \\
       xy & y^2+1 & yz \\
       xz & yz & z^2+1 \\
       \end{bmatrix} , B=\begin{bmatrix}
       x^2+1 & x^2 & x^2 \\
       y^2 & y^2+1 & z^2 \\
       z^2 & z^2 & z^2+1 \\
       \end{bmatrix}$$
   Then points 1 and 2 let us translate the given algorithm into $$B=M(1,x)M(2,y)M(3,z)AM(1,\frac1x)M(2,\frac1y)M(3,\frac1z)$$
   since $|M(1,x)| |M(1,1/x)|=1$, the result follows from point 3.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I think of it, we can think of such  a determinant as a scalar triple product of three vector functions. Explicitly speaking:

$$ D(x,y)= \vec{f}(x,y) \cdot \vec{h}(x,y) \times \vec{g}(x,y)$$

You can imagine [three vector fields in space](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4CnKQiPVxv0), and the above expression takes those three vectors corresponding to that vector field at a point and evaluates their scalar triple product.

Now, if we have a factorable vector field meaning something of the form:

$$ \vec{f}(x,y) = h(x,y) \vec{q}(x,y)$$

That is a vector field which can be written in terms of a 'modulating scale factor' which varies from point to point times another a vector field, then, we can pull of these scale factors from the scalar triple product and just take the scalar product of the 'factored' vector functions.

Hopefully that makes sense.